# Увеличение и уменьшение переменной в заданных пределах

Tags: javascript

Есть два дива и код:

```
document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function() {                  
    img--;
    SaveFon();                  
}

document.querySelector('.but4').onclick = function() {                  
    img++;
    SaveFon();                  
}
```

Соответственно `LS` тоже есть, просто это не в тему. Так вот, необходимо, чтобы при каждом нажатии на див "`but3`" переменная изменялась на "1" в меньшую сторону. А при нажатии на "`but4`" - прибавлялась на "1". Но при этом, чтобы меньше "1" быть не могло, т.е. если переменная "1" и нажать на "`but3`", то число станет равно "20". Как и если дойдёт до числа 20 (нажатием на `but4`), автоматически число снова стало "1".

Не могу понять как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать условный [оператор `if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Нужно проверить текущее значение:

```
if (img == 20) 
if (img == 1)
```

И в зависимости от результата присвоить нужное значение:

```
document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function() {                  
    if(img == 1){ // если переменная "1"
        img = 20; // то число станет равно "20"
    }else{ // иначе
        img--; // все как было
    }
    SaveFon();                  
}

document.querySelector('.but4').onclick = function() {                  
    if(img == 20){ // если дойдёт до числа 20 
        img = 1; // автоматически число снова стало "1"
    }else{ // иначе
        img++; // все как было
    }
    SaveFon();                  
}
```

либо можно использовать [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

```
document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function() {                  
    img = img == 1 ? 20 : img-1;
    SaveFon();                  
}
```

Comment: Вроде всё отлично работает, но не подскажите еще.. используя первый вариант, при нажатии на див, который увеличивает переменную на "1".. при нажатии еще раз, переменная уже не увеличивается и всё равно равна "1". Как это исправить?

Comment: @user250973, странно, такого поведения не должно быть: https://jsfiddle.net/x8n81xjp/

Comment: всё, проблема решилась.. по-другому, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var img = 0;
document.querySelector('.but3').onclick = function() {
  img--;
  if(img<1)img=20;
  console.log(img);
}

document.querySelector('.but4').onclick = function() {
  img++;
  if(img>20)img=0;
  console.log(img);
}
```

```html
<button class='but3'>-</button>
<button class='but4'>+</button>
```